# Javascript function scope variable is available in the global scope

Tags: javascript

In JavaScript, variables created within a function only have scope only within that function: if that's the case, why does the following code produce the output 1? Surely `x` cannot be accessed from outside of `foo` ?

```
function foo(){
  x = 1;
}
foo()
console.log(x) // '1'
```

Comment: This code will throw an exception in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode). You should always use strict mode.

Comment: *variable's created within a function only have scope only within that function* —  that is not true in the case of *implicit global* variables like yours.

Comment: Simply never ever ever use undeclared variables.

Comment: `x` is not declared inside `foo`. You are just assigning to an undeclared variable.

Answer (score 6):

Because you have assigned to a variable which is defined without `var, let or const`. And because your code in *not strict mode*, it is assigned to the global object's (`window`) property with name `x`. You can uncomment the `use strict` part and will see an exception.

```js
// 'use strict';

function foo() {
   x = 1;
   console.log(window.x);
}

foo();
console.log(window.x);
```

If you declare with keywords you can not access it outside the function and it will not be in the `window` object.

```js
function foo() {
   let x = 1;
   console.log(x);
}

foo();
console.log(window.x);
```

Comment: Perhaps add a few more examples with, say, `"use strict"`, `let` / `var`?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you only initialize the variable in side the function without var, let or const so JavaScript threat it as a globe variable

```js
function foo(){
  x = 1;
}
foo()
console.log(x) // '1'
```

Following is how it work if you use var, let or const

```js
function foo(){
 var x = 1;
 let y = 1;
 const z = 1;
}
foo()
console.log(x)
//console.log(y)
//console.log(z)
```

Comment: You should have left it how it was, JS will stop on `console.log(x)` as it fails so others will never be called

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Thanks forgot to comment those lines