# What is the difference between window.foo() and foo()?

Tags: javascript, this

I know that in 'use strict' `this` inside the functions gets `undefined` value, but I mentioned that if I call `window.foo()` instead of `foo()`, `this` gets `window` value, here is code example:

```
'use strict';

function logThis() {
    console.log(this);
}

window.logThis() // window
logThis() // undefined
```

I would like to understand why this happens.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514382/global-functions-in-javascript

Comment: "I know that in 'use strict' this inside functions gets undefined value," — No. That's only true if you call a function with no context. The behaviour of `this` is all other situations (e.g. then there is a context, for arrow functions, for use of bind/call/apple, or for use of new) is unchanged.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47909969/javascript-function-scope-variable-is-available-in-the-global-scope

Comment: [This may provide a little bit more of an insight @alexanderrodin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14328520/2647442)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Global functions in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29514382/global-functions-in-javascript)